# Excel VBA code that searches multiple documents for a text

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for help, I have a very basic knowledge of VBA and can't perform complex tasks, would someone be able to provide the base of the code and I'll be able to study it and expand on it?

The code should be able to perform the following task:

Using a list of document names in excel, open those documents (word documents) and search the first page for a specific text. If the text exists return TRUE, else FALSE.

Please note the documents are all stored in sub folders.

Thank you,

Comment: What *specifically* do you need help with?  Which part of the process are you having a problem with? Right now your question is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tree different question you have to ask yourself before posting:

I will try to answer it in the way you asked:

1 - Read documents name from the excel file

```
Dim fileNames as new Collection   

For Each name in Range("names")
    fileNames.Add name
Next name
```

2 - Open Word documents

Add the Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library to your references, and use the Word API to open and read the document.

```
Dim doc As Word.Document
Set doc = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=DocumentPath, Visible:=False)
```

3 - Find text in the active document

```
Dim myRng as Word.Range
Set myRng = doc.Content
```

then use the find object for your purpose, take a look at the documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/find-object-word